# How do i break the loop when connection fails?

Tags: batch-file, ping

Im working on a ping batch program.
What i wanna learn is how do i skip the loop when the connection is dead?
For an example:

```
@echo off
:1
ping www.stackoverflow.com
(I guess) if errorlevel 1 set errorlev=1
If errorlevel 1 goto 2
goto 1
:2
Echo ping failed!
Title ping failed!
color c
```

Comment: There is a break command in bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might try this:

```
:back
ping www.stackoverflow.com >nul && goto:back
Echo ping failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to ping forever until the ping fails, then stop?

```
@echo off
:1
ping -n 1 www.stackoverflow.com | find "Reply from">nul2>nul && goto :1
echo ping failed!
title ping failed!
color c
```

Note: I piped to find instead of checking ERRORLEVEL because some Windows versions aren't consistent with setting the ERRORLEVEL for certain failure conditions. See the below example.

```
C:\Users\Me>ping -n 1 192.168.1.2

Pinging 192.168.1.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.102: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.2:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

C:\Users\Me>echo %errorlevel%
0
```